# What camera for panoramic shot?

Tags: digital, travel

I'm interested in capturing panoramic shots. Any advice what camera to use?

Comment: Could you please stop adding links to a well-known camera vendor in every one of your posts? It's not necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by panoramic shots? This can mean different things to different people. Is there a particular field of view you want to cover, or do you simply want an image with a ratio of, for example, 3:1? Are you looking for a digital camera, or would a (used) film camera be acceptable? Are you thinking of a camera with a rotating lens? Will you digitally stitch images together to get your result? Lots of options.

Comment: Also, Sony (at least) has in-camera stitching with their Sweep Panorama mode. Maybe this is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

In more or less descending order of importance:

- One that lets you control both exposure and focus manually so that you can use the exact same parameters for every shot.
- One that is easy to use on a tripod, and has provision that allows use of a wired cable release to operate the shutter.
- One that has the ability to take photos that are relatively distortion free. This means a lens that demonstrates neither pincushion nor barrel distortion, at least at the intended focal length of a zoom lens.
- A lens that is reasonably sharp from the center to the corners with little or uncorrected spherical or chromatic aberration, at least at the intended aperture setting. Even though it is very expensive and a fantastic lens for certain things, the Canon EF 85mm f/1.2 L would probably not make a great panorama lens due to intentionally uncorrected spherical aberration that gives it a unique "look".
- One that doesn't blow your entire budget on the camera and lens. You're also going to need a pretty good set of tripod legs and a very good tripod head that will allow you to pivot the camera around the optical center of the lens (often erroneously referred to as the *nodal point*).
- One that is compatible with high capacity memory cards. For some projects you will find you need to take a LOT of frames.

Beyond that it all depends on your budget and if you want to jump in with both feet or start out a little slower and use entry level or consumer level gear that allows you do discover specifically what *you* need to create the panoramic images *you* envision.